# Getting back to the same instance of Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

My problem is that I assigned a shortcut to Outlook like this: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" and this worked fine and just like I wanted it to: when pressing the key I came back to this oneandonly instance of Outlook all the time.

Then something happened and I lost this behavior with the shortcut key, so now when I press the shortcut key it starts a new instance all the time...

I have tried with various switches my best so far is: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /edit which takes me back but this prompts me that the switch is invalid all the time.

So is there a switch to get me to the state where I just get back to Outlook, without prompts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch should be /recycle, not /edit.

Comment: Correct. This forces outlook to look for any running instances and re-open them