# Getting back to the same instance of Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting back to the same instance of Outlook 2007?](https://superuser.com/questions/35629/getting-back-to-the-same-instance-of-outlook-2007)

My problem is that I assigned a shortcut to Outlook like this:
 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE"
and this worked fine and just like I wanted it to: when pressing the key I came back to this oneandonly instance of Outlook all the time.

Then something happened and I lost this behavior with the shortcut key, so now when I press the shortcut key it starts a new instance all the time...

I have tried with various switches my best so far is: 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /edit 
which takes me back but this prompts me that the switch is invalid all the time.

So is there a switch to get me to the state where I just get back to Outlook, without prompts?

/Regards
Christer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is short:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle
```

Answer (score 0):

Ot sounds like you had minimize to tray enabled before and it isn't enabled now.

Start Outlook
Right click on the Outlook icon in the tray and select Hide when minimized. This hides Outlook's taskbar button and gives the impression you're starting Outlook at the same view when you click the shortcut.